# Report of Account Related Contacts infromation

Tags: reporting, customization, joined-reports, custom-reports

[image]i created Account Related 5 Contacts, Each **Contact** having **Status__c** (Picklist) Fieild.
my question is ..
Contact_1 and Contact_2 is having Status__c is **A**,
Conatct_3 and Conatct_4 is having Status__c is **B**,
Conatct_5 Status__c Field is having **C**, 
How to get this information in Reports.

Please give any suggestions..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you can user summery report as shown below[image]

[image]

Comment: i tried this same this i am not getting any idea...

Comment: please check screenshot carefully..after preview there is tabular format in your screenshot, make it summery and then drag the coulmn status below

Comment: Yes Thanks @ Ashwini Dengi , then finally I want the Percentage of Each Group of Status Related Percentage....
Example: Status__c - A Related Contact Count is 2, in Total Contacts 5. Means 2/5*100% == 40% Like this way .... how to do

Comment: you can click on  add chart button.. then in the formatting user %..i have added the screenshot above again

Comment: you can add this chart above or below the existing report

Comment: Let me know if you need any more info @user33433

Answer (score 0):

You can use report type as contacts and account.
In coulmn field add the picklist status field and other related fields.[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Ashwini Dengi, I Did this one, but i don't want individual infromation, i want the Contact_1 and Contact_2 is Primary So The Count is 2. This format only i need... Can u please check once...